# Write data from data base to txt file

Tags: php, html, mysql

I can not write data from data base to txt file, is written last record from data base only.

Sample working code:

```
include '01_config.php';
db_connect();
if(empty($_POST))
{
    define('DB_HOST','localhost');
    define('DB_USER','root');
    define('DB_PASS','password');
    define('DB_NAME','data_base');
    $select_db = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME);
    if($select_db)
    {
        mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
    }
    else
    {
        die('***');
    }

    $query = "SELECT user_id, user_email FROM users WHERE user_position = 'yes' ORDER BY user_id ASC";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if($result===false && trim(mysql_error))
    {
        echo("*** \n");
    }
        while($art = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $out[]=$art;
    }
    $i=0;
    echo "|form action=\"11.php\" method=\"post\"|\n";
    foreach($out as $art){
        $art['user_email'] = htmlspecialchars($art['user_email'],ENT_QUOTES);
        echo  <<<EOT
        <textarea name="text$i" style="width:450px; height:190px; border: 3px solid #cccccc; font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif; font-size: 12px;">
        BEGIN:VCARD
        EMAIL;TYPE=INTERNET:{$art['user_email']}
        END:VCARD
        |/textarea||br /|
        EOT;
        $i++;
    }
    echo '|input type="submit" value="Save to file" /||/form|';
}else if(isset($_POST['text0']) && isset($_POST['text1']) && isset($_POST['text2']) && isset($_POST['text3'])){
    $file = "13.txt";
    $fp = fopen($file, "w");
    flock($fp, 2);
    fwrite($fp, $_POST['text0']);
    fwrite($fp, $_POST['text1']);
    fwrite($fp, $_POST['text2']);
    fwrite($fp, $_POST['text3']);
    flock($fp, 3);
    fclose($fp);
    echo "successfully saved!<br />";
}else{
    die("Error!!!");
}
db_close();
```

How to change code to be written all of the records from the database?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

(There are changed some `"<"` and `">"` to `"|"`, sorry.)

Comment: You are writing the `$_POST` content to the file, am I wright ?

Comment: Yes, I'm writing the $_POST content to the txt file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just to show how it can be done . You would need to start using `MySQLi` or `PDO` .
Try something along these lines and then try to incorporate it into your code :

( I tested and it worked for me )

```
$query = "
    SELECT user_id, user_email
    FROM users
    WHERE user_position = 'yes'
    ORDER BY user_id ASC";

//  $query = "SELECT user_email FROM users ORDER BY user_id ASC";

$result = mysql_query( $query );

$totalNumRows = mysql_num_rows( $result );
echo 'Total rows : ' ,$totalNumRows ,'<br>';

if( $totalNumRows > 0 )
{
    $file = "13.txt";
    $fp = fopen($file, "w");
    flock($fp, 2);
    while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) )
    {
        fwrite( $fp, $row['user_email'] );
    //  fwrite( $fp, "\r\n" );  // If you need line breaks
    }
    flock( $fp ,3 );
    fclose( $fp );
}
```

Comment: Works for me also :), many thanks. I'll try to add it into my code, but I see that I can't use the POST method.

Comment: But this is not a problem. The most important for me is that works fantastically, thanks again for your help, best regards!

Answer (score 0):

The way you `fopen()` the file deletes all previous contents. Change mode from `"w"` (overwrite) to `"a"` (append). Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

Comment: Overwrite mode is fine for me, this is not a problem. The problem is how to write all records form one column of data base in one time, when I press the "Save to file" button in my form. I have column user_email with 100 email addresses and when I try write this addresses to txt file I have seved one only (last one or first one, according to my database query - ASC or DESC).